# Setting enum flags from integer value

Tags: c#, enums, flags

```
CompBitsList companyBit;
public CompBitsList CompanyBit { get => companyBit; set => companyBit= value; }

[Flags]
public enum CompBitsList
{
   None = 0
   BitOption1 = 1,
   BitOption2 = 2,
   BitOption3 = 4,
   BitOption4 = 8,
   BitOption5 = 16,
   BitOption6 = 32,
}
```

Lets say I have the integer value 22 that would contain the enum flags BitOption2, BitOption3 and BitOption5 (2+4+16). Is there a way to automate this so that I can pass the integer value and have the enum variable CompanyBit set automatically?

```
companyBit = CompBitsList.BitOption2 | CompBitsList.BitOption3 | CompBitsList.BitOption5
```

I'm not very familar with enums but I would prefer not to do the method above so any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try `companyBit = (CompBitsList) 22;`.  You could also create a `SetCompanyBit(int intValue)` function that just does the cast.  But, you'll hate yourself in 5 years when you go back to maintain your code.  The advantage of all that typing is that it is self documenting.

Comment: Also, are you NOT using `[Flags]` for your enum, as this is obviously a bit flag enum?

Comment: @Sach Sorry I am just forgot to add it.

Comment: @Flydog57 I think this may work lol I didn't imagine it would be that simple, and the only time I would be setting companyBit like that would be in the startup of the program by setting the value from an integer based on configurations.

Comment: Here's some further reading. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c

Comment: One thing you can do in configurations is parse a config string directly.  If you have a config entry like `<add key="companyBit" value = "BitOption2,BitOption3,BitOption5" />` (note the commas), then you can take that config string and parse it with `Enum.TryParse<CompBitsList>` and get a 22-valued `CompBitList` value directly. _(Note, this requires the `[Flags]` attribute on your enum)_

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast the `int` to an instance of `CompBitsList`.

```csharp
CompBitsList companyBit = (CompBitsList)22;
companyBit.HasFlag(CompBitsList.BitOption2); // True
companyBit.HasFlag(CompBitsList.BitOption3); // True
companyBit.HasFlag(CompBitsList.BitOption5); // True
companyBit.HasFlag(CompBitsList.BitOption6); // False
```

You can also define a value on that enum that represents a combination of flags, if it makes sense and you'll be combining those flags a lot.

```csharp
[Flags]
public enum CompBitsList
{
   None = 0
   BitOption1 = 1,
   BitOption2 = 2,
   BitOption3 = 4,
   BitOption4 = 8,
   BitOption5 = 16,
   BitOption6 = 32,
   BitOptions2And3And5 = BitOption2 | BitOption3 | BitOption5 //or just 22
}
```